# How to post HTTPRequest with cookies in alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to post Cookie in Alamofire.
I'm storing cookies after the first login.
After logins, I must post this cookie together.
But it doesn't work.

```swift
// 1. restore cookie
let cookie = HTTPCookieStorage.restore() // my custom function.

// 2. set cookie
Alamofire.Session.default.sessionConfiguration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookie)

// 3. check cookie
print(Alamofire.Session.default.sessionConfiguration.httpCookieStorage?.cookies?.first) // Cookies were set correctly.

// 4. post request
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("fail")
        }
}
```

But response is always fail.
Am I wrong to set cookies?
I need your help. Thanks.

=============================== Addition

Thank you for your answer.
I had tried your code like this.

```swift
guard let cookie = HTTPCookieStorage.restore() else { return }
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookie)
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)

session.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
        print("success")
    } else {
        print("fail")
    }
```

But sometimes it succeeds but most crash.
Crash message is `Fatal error: dataTask received data for incorrect Request subclass: nil: file /Users/J/Documents/AJLiOS/Pods/Alamofire/Source/SessionDelegate.swift, line 189`

Do you have any doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the the `configuration` of a `URLSession` after the `URLSession` has been initialized, see [Apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411477-configuration)

In Alamofire 5, you can initialize your own `Session` instance and set the cookies there:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(HTTPCookieStore.restore())
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Can you please see my addition contents?

Comment: That error means Alamofire has lost the association between the `Request` and its `URLSessionTask`. Are you trying to restore from the background? Alamofire doesn't support that.

Comment: Or, it could be that your `Session` has been deinited, depending on the context where you create it. You need to keep a reference alive, usually through a singleton.

Comment: I create a `session` as you told me, and if the response is successful, then I use the usual AF.request(blah blah...) method. Does that mean I should continue to use the sessions created?

Comment: Yes, as the `AF` APIs use the `default` `Session` instance, which has its own state. You need to keep your created `Session` around and use it to make all requests if you want to share cookies.

Comment: Thank you. I changed according to your advice and it worked well.